# How to display and hide image by view height

Tags: html, css

I should display images on two sides of a page,but sometimes, the page's height is less than the (combined) height of all the images.

I've tried solving this issue with the help of media queries

```
 .image1{
            display: none;
            width: 35em;
            position: absolute;
            top: 26em
        }
        .image2{
            display: none;
            width: 35em;
            position: absolute;
            top: 78em;
            right: 0;
        }
        .image3{
            display: none;
            width: 35em;
            position: absolute;
            top: 120em;
            left: 0;
        }

        @media (min-height: 0vh) and (max-height: 15vh)  {
            .image1{
                display: block !important;
            }
        }
        @media (min-height: 16vh) and (max-height: 25vh)  {
            .image1{
                display: block !important;
            }
            .image2{
                display: block !important;
            }
        }
        @media (min-height: 26vh) and (max-height: 900vh)  {
            .image1{
                display: block !important;
            }
            .image2{
                display: block !important;
            }
            .image3{
                display: block !important;
            }
        }
```

What should be the outcome:

[image]

Comment: I've rephrased your question, please have a look if I made your question more clearer. Could you also post your HTML in order to create a [mre]

Comment: FWIW When I find I am doing `block !important;` it means I need to adjust my CSS so I can remove the `!important` - BUT, why are you repeating that?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question: "*I should display images on two sides of a page*" sounds good, and understandable "*but sometimes, the page's height is less than the (combined) height of all the images*" - if the images are side-by-side I don't understand why the combined height is a problem? And, obviously, could you please add the relevant HTML, a picture and some CSS (without context) tells us absolutely nothing useful.

Comment: I started to see if there was a way to get a viable answer here but given the image and the description this is going to need some clarification as they do not seem to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media  screen and (max-height: 480px) {
  /*code*/
}
```

15vh, 25vh, ..? You may use px, em, or 100vh. You can't use 15vh, 25vh.

A view always has a 100vh and 100vw which are the entire height and width of the view since they are relative terms.  Since these ARE relative terms for a view using 25vh for example will not work here since a view always have a 25vh.  Think of this as 25% of the view height. Consider for example you always have a 25% of your height no matter how tall you are but the actual measure value of 25% of a 8 foot tall person is 2 feet but on a 4 foot tall person it is 1 foot.

Comment: I added some more text to give viewers a visual of what you said and more "why your cannot".  Feel free to revise my edit.

Comment: Okay, thanks :)